# Making img same height as div in responsive design

Tags: css, wordpress

See attached image for reference. How do I get the image to the right to be of same height as the two boxes to the left. It needs to be responsive, right now it works at a certain window size but doesn't adapt well to smaller window sizes. I thought it could be acheived by using background-image instead of img but I'm using worpress and the_post_thumbnail() function to get the image which returns a img element. Is it possible to to adapt the img using CSS to acheive this effect?
This is my HTML structure:

```
<div class="event">
        <div class="event-top-half">
            <div class="event-date">
                <span class="PLD">22</span> 
                <span class="PLM">Jun</span>
            </div>
            <div class="event-image "><a href="[...]"><img width="719" height="267" src="[...]"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="event-name">
            <span><a href="https://1demo.dk/mva/event/eurotox-2020/">Mobilising our Entrepreneurs of tomorrow – session 4</a></span>
        </div>
    <div class="event-info">15:30 - 17:00 / online</div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot of the problem]

Comment: This can surely be done with CSS but, I'm missing  the CSS referencing to this problem.
Can you provided us with the CSS that affect all elements within the event block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something you can do, reading the wordpress doc's is using another function for getting your image.

using `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` [explaination here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/)

you can make something like this:

```
<div class="event-image" style="background: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>')"> </div>
```

then all you would need is some css like this(its just a guess, it might take some different values):

```
.event-top-half{
   display:flex;
   flex-direction:row;
   height: fit-content;
   width: 100%; /*or anything you need*/
 }
 .event-date{
   width: 30%;
   height: 200px;/*anything you need here*/
 }
 .event-image{
   background-position: center center!important;
   background-size: cover!important;
   background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
   width: 70%;
   height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Great suggestion! Didn't know about the get_the_post_thumbnail_url() though I did actually try to find a function that did just that. I will test your suggestion later when I've got time.

Comment: for sure, play around with it and if you can't figure it out. comment here again. i'd be happy to update my answer to suit new problems

Comment: Your suggestion works perfectly. However I get into problems when trying to adapt the design for different window sizes. The images sometimes have text near the edges that disappears when the width of the div is smaller than the image. Is it possible to have fixed proportions for the .event-image div and adapt the height and width of the .event-date and span.PLD/span.PLM responsively? The images will have the same proportions (currently it is 719x267px but it may change).

Comment: yes you can make the image have `background-size: contain` and set a width/height for it, and then make the `.event-date` `height: auto`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fixed pixel values you should use % if you want it to be responsive.

Try this: 
`<div class="event-image "><a href="[...]"><img height="100%" src="[...]"></a></div>` 
or
`<div class="event-image "><a href="[...]"><img width="100%" src="[...]"></a></div>`

Comment: Thanks for a really quick answer. Problem is the img element is returned as it is by the wp funciton. Not sure how I can change the attributes of that element. That's why CSS would be simpler for me to use. But I'll look into if I can change how the element is returned.

Comment: Changing height to 100% doesn't seem to work when I try it in the console. Not sure if this is the solution I need.